# Multipart, how to send file correct

Tags: http, post, flutter, multipartform-data

I'trying to send a Multipart form data, through Flutter but the response api can't get the image file. I created a Backend just to debug my call and I got this:

My code:

```
Map<String, String> fields = {
      "label":'-Ll7XfpsPLd_w5kz-D0m' 
    };
MultipartRequest request = MultipartRequest(
      'POST',
      Uri.parse(url),
    );
    request.fields.addAll(fields);
    request.files.add(
      MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'image',
        imagem.readAsBytesSync(),
        contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpeg'),
      )
    );
    return request.send();
```

The server answer:

```
received fields:

 { label: [ '-Ll7XfpsPLd_w5kz-D0m' ],
  image:
   [ '\M-o\M ... A LOT OF DATA]}
```

Then a made a HTML page just to test:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://172.20.10.2:5002/upload" >
    <input type="text" name="zava" value="Zava" /> <br />
    <input type="file" name="image" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" /> <br />
</form>
```

And received de server answer:

```
received fields:

 { zava: [ 'Zava' ] }

received files:

 { image:
   [ { fieldName: 'image',
       originalFilename: 'Grifo.png',
       path: '/tmp/0wvX_w8W5Mw_7flqIdK0b1xX.png',
       headers: [Object],
       size: 114862 } ] }
```

What's wrong with my code? Why de Multipart does not send the file as a file?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that if you pass the optional param `filename` of the `MultipartFile` the request works correctly.

Just have to do something like this:

```
      MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'image',
        imagem.readAsBytesSync(),
        contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpeg'),
        filename: 'dummy.jpg'
      )
```

I had opened a bug on flutter about the request without filename (if must be repaired or the documentation changed)...